# Equations of motion of the metric in Classical Dilaton Gravity

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, modified-gravity, equations-of-motion

In these [lecture notes by Strominger](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9501071) section 3.3 we derive the equations of motion of the Classical Dilaton Gravity action
$$
S = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int{d^2x}{\sqrt{-g}e^{-2\phi}\left(R +4 (\nabla\phi)^2+4\lambda^2\right)}\tag{3.6}
$$

The equations of motion for the metric are
$$
2 e^{-2\phi}(\nabla_\mu\nabla_\nu\phi+g_{\mu\nu}((\nabla\phi)^2-\nabla^2\phi-\lambda^2)=0\tag{3.7}
$$

Then by introducing light-cone coordinates and gauge fixing the metric we have
$$
g_{+-}=-\frac{1}{2}e^{2\rho}\qquad g_{++}=g_{--}=0\tag{3.12}
$$

Finally for the $g_{++}$ and $g_{--}$ the equations of motion in  terms of the light-cone coordinates give
$$
e^{-2\phi}(4\partial_+\rho\partial_+\phi-2\partial_+^2\phi)=0
\\e^{-2\phi}(4\partial_-\rho\partial_-\phi-2\partial_-^2\phi)=0\tag{3.15}
$$

I don't understand where the last 2 equations come from. Are they not supposed to be the components $_{++}$ and $_{--}$ of the equation of motion of the metric found before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To derive (3.15), you need only (3.7).
The $++$ component of (3.7) gives the first one in (3.15); while the $--$ component give the second one.

For example, $++$ component gives $2 e^{-2\phi}(\nabla_+\nabla_+\phi)=0$, where I have used gauge condition $g_{++}=0$; on the other side $\nabla_+\nabla_+\phi$ is $\partial_+\partial_+\phi-2\partial_+\rho\partial_+\phi$, where $2\partial_+\rho$ comes from a component of Christoffel symbol; as a result, we have $2 e^{-2\phi}(\partial_+\partial_+\phi-2\partial_+\rho\partial_+\phi)=0$.